# Degenerate or nondegenerate bi-linear function

Tags: linear-algebra

I am having trouble with deciding if a function is degenerate or not.

Suppose that for each x and y in $P_n$ (polynomials) the function w is defined by w(x,y)=x(1)y(1)

I believe that my function is bi-linear because $w(ax+bt,y)=(ax(1)+bt(1))y(1) = ax(1)y(1)+bt(1)y(1)=aw(x,y)+bw(t,y)$. How do I show if it is degenerate or not?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Actually your function w is not linear. You can try to prove that by showing that :

$$\exists P,Q,P',Q' \in \mathbb{K}[X] \quad and \quad\exists a\in \mathbb{K} , \quad w((P,Q)+a(P',Q')) \neq w(P,Q)+aw(P',Q'))$$

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I believe that my function is bi-linear because $w(ax+bt,y)=(ax(1)+bt(1))y(1) = ax(1)y(1)+bt(1)y(1)=aw(x,y)+bw(t,y)$. I really don't know what to do now... :P

Comment: Then you function is indeed degenerate, if you chose x as the null polynomial you have :
$$\forall y, w(0,y)=0$$

Comment: ok thanks... That's what I needed to know. So I pick x or y and set it as the null polynomial and if I get 0 then it is degenerate? Is that correct? Or do I always pick x?

Comment: In the general case you have to verify that :
$\exists x_{0}$ such as $\forall y, w(x_{0},y) = 0$ and $\exists y_{0}$ such as $\forall x, w(x,y_{0}) = 0$
But here since w is symetric I only checked for x :)